# nginx uwsgi 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

My nginx and uwsgi configuration perfectly working for first one or two requests . Then nginx showing 502 Bad Gateway .When I restart the uwsgi service , same thing happens again. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Here is my all conf and error log:

`nginx conf`:

```
upstream book {
    server unix:///tmp/book.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name example.com;
    ......
   add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
   add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

   charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

    location /media {
        alias /home/prism/prod/example.com/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/prism/prod/example.com/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass book;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }

}
```

`/var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log`

```
2016/05/25 17:44:26 [error] 5230#5230: *214 connect() to unix:///tmp/book.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 27.*.*.*, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/book.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

`hiren.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/prism/prod/example.com
home = /home/prism/prod/example.com/.env
module=hiren.wsgi
master=True
process = 5
pidfile=/tmp/book.pid
socket= /tmp/book.sock
vacuum=True
max-requests=5000
daemonize=/home/prism/prod/example.com/hiren.log
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
die-on-term = true
```

and service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve example.com

[Service]
User=prism
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/prism/prod/example.com; source .env/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini hiren.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Bad Gateway error indicates the link between nginx and your app is broken, so I wouldn't suspect nginx conf here. This is usually because the app itself is not responding. Have you checked the uWSGI service is still running ? Do you have any log of uWSGI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by tweaking systemd script

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve example.com

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'su prism; cd /home/prism/prod/example.com; source .env/bin/activate; uwsgi --ini hiren.ini'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run uwsgi and your .ini file within your virtual environment, and nginx is starting adequately, the issue is then with a systemd file.